# Change Data on certain tabs with tab names to change in another tab

Tags: excel, vba

I feel like I'm on the tail end of this. I have a workbook with hundreds of tabs. As part of a larger macro, I am bringing 52 additional tabs in that will analyze data from the existing tabs in the workbook. I already wrote VBA to bring the tabs in, while turning off automatic updating to keep it fast :D.

Now, I am trying to, for the tabs I brought in and whose names are listed on a tab "Tab Names", change the data to tables and after that turn back on automatic updating (they are indirect formulas). This is what I have so far:

```
Sub TabstoTables()

Dim tablename As Variant
Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim rng As Range

For Each tablename In Sheets("Tab Names").Range("A1:A5")
    Set TargetSheet = Worksheets(CStr(tablename))
    Set rng = Range(TargetSheet.Range("A1"), TargetSheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
    Set tbl = TargetSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes)
    tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium15"
Next tablename

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

End Sub
```

I am getting a **Subscript out of range** for the following line:

```
Set TargetSheet = Worksheets(CStr(tablename))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Minor points for neatness: `Dim tablename as Range`, `In Worksheets("Tab Names").Range("A1:A5").Cells`, and `Worksheets(CStr(tablename.value))` - also, consider checking if the sheet with that name actually exists first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Dim tablename as Range` and then switch your error line for:

```
Set TargetSheet = ThisworkBook.Sheets(tablename)
```

Comment: I get a type mismatch error when I swap this instead of the targetsheet above!

Comment: Could be because you improperly declared a table name. I updated, try again?

Comment: Still getting an error. The Tab Names tab just has a litst A1:A63 of the names of tabs I wan't to change. They aren't technically a table name? I'm newer to VBA so I'm not 100% sure of what I am doing, ha!

Comment: This should work then. Have you verified your list matches tab names exactly? Lagging/extra spaces in the table or the actual tab name will mess this up if they are not exact. I would start there. You can use `msgbox tablename` tbefore `Set TargetSheet` to verify you are getting the right input.

Comment: Yes! Great call, there was one tab that was spelled incorrectly. Thanks so much!